# Run an executable on host machine from docker container

Tags: docker, busybox, op-tee

I have an executable on the host machine and I want to run it from Docker. It's important to run it FROM Docker, so you should call it inside, and it should call the executable on the host machine.
Summerize: I need something that connect the Docker container with the host machine, and I can call the executable in the docker container, what calls the same executable on the host machine. Is this possible?

I tried volumes, but it didn't work for me, or I used it in a bad way.

Comment: Do you want to run the executable in the host environment or docker environment? If you need it to run in the docker environment, the container should have all dependencies present and the executable should be built to be run in the container. If it needs to run on the host, you can use a privileged container with shared namespaces if required.

Comment: Part of the point of Docker is that this is difficult.  If running a host process is a key goal of your application, it probably also needs to run outside of Docker.